# Limit Sell and Stop Loss Different Quantities

Tags: stocks, limit-order

I own 100 shares of a stock at $40.00 per share.  I would like to sell all 100 shares if the price falls below $36.  But, if the stock were to double to $80 per share, I would like to sell 50 shares thereby recovering my initial investment on then remaining 50 shares.  How would I enter transactions to work in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

Use a 'One Cancels Other' order if your broker offers it.  Two orders are placed and if one of the orders is executed, the other is cancelled automatically. In your case you would place a stop loss order with a limit limit order.

If there's an issue with the disparate size of the two orders then use a 'One Cancels All' order.  Here, you can place multiple orders and when one is filled, the other orders are  cancelled.